# Focus on Input Not Working

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to get .focus() to work with a slide-in div, but no matter what I do whenever the div appears, the cursor isn't in the chosen input field.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mobius1/36n8y/ (FIXED)

Click the 'Quote' button to slide the div in. I need the cursor to appear in the first input field (#name).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback function of `show`:

```
$("#slide").hide().delay(500).show("drop", {
    direction: "up"
}, 500, function() {
    $("#name").focus();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/L366u/1/

Answer (score 0):

Focus within the callback:

```
$("#slide")
  .hide()
  .delay(500)
  .show("drop", { direction: "up" }, 500, function() {
    $("#name").focus();   
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L366u/2/

Answer (score 0):

change as follows-->

```
 // focus on first input of slide (not working)
        setTimeout(function(){$("#name").focus();}, 500);
```